# HWND Type Mismatch

Tags: html, vba

I am receiving a 'Type Mistmatch' error on the HWNDSrc = objIE.HWND line below but HWND is a Long property & HWNDSrc has been set as Long

```
Sub Test()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
HWNDSrc = objIE.HWND
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine for me... of course I had to remove the `SetForegroundWindow` line tho, because you did not include its definition. Note: You probably will need to add this too: `objIE.Visible = True` if you are expecting to be able to set it to the foreground.

Comment: That's very strange - any idea why this would drive an error for me? Is it a setting I need to adjust?

Comment: Looks like the guy below has the answer. I am using Win 10 64 bit OS, and 64 bit Office.

Comment: I have removed the SetForegroundWindow code but still receiving the same error. If we are both running the exact same code should it not work for both of us? Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you running 64 bit office and 64 bit windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetForegroundWindow` is a Windows API function that takes and returns `LongPtr` on 64-bit Office, and `Long` on 32 bit Office, so you need to account for that using conditional compilation constants. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481674/vba-api-declarations-bring-window-to-front-regardless-of-application) for reference.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr

#Else
    Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If


Sub Test()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

#If VBA7 Then
    Dim HWNDSrc As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
#End If

    HWNDSrc = objIE.hwnd

    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome - it was the LongPtr property. Thanks guys!!

Comment: @Mturks83 Good to hear! If you wouldn't mind to go ahead and accept this as the answer, so that his post can be closed, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Mturks83 near the top (left) of the answer, under the up/down voting buttons